# PHP get redirect URL

Tags: php, redirect, curl, guzzle

I've already read some other questions regarding the same problem and tried the curl examples there. However these examples don't work for this specific url `http://www.prisjakt.no/redirect.php?prisid=182556713`. All I get is the same link with the redirect in it.

Do you have a solution to get url of the followed link, in this case `http://www.siba.no/tv-lyd-bilde/hodetelefoner/lukkede-hodetelefoner/sennheiser-momentum-109434`?

A solution using Guzzle would also be fine.

Thank you!

Edit: The problem seems to be that the redirect is made via JS and not with a header.

Comment: Guzzle is a HTTP client, hence relies on correct HTTP headers to function as excepted. As you noted, the redirect is done via JS - so you need to parse the result and manually extract the target URL.

Answer (score 2):

Guzzle does provide some configuration settings for [Redirects in Requests](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#allow-redirects)

You could "trap" the redirect by adding an [Event Listener](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html) to the BeforeEvent like so:

```
$request = $client->createRequest('GET', $url);
$request->getEmitter()->on('before', function (BeforeEvent $event) {
    // do something with the event.
});
$response = $client->send($request);
```

Then within the listener you can grab the url of the new request by calling:

```
$event->getRequest()->getUrl()
```

For example:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$request = $client->createRequest('GET', 'http://www.google.com');
$request->getEmitter()->on('before', function (GuzzleHttp\Event\BeforeEvent $e) {
    echo $e->getRequest()->getUrl() . PHP_EOL;
});
$response = $client->send($request);
```

Results in:

> - http://www.google.com
> - http://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=LogLVe7tC8zJsQfKsoGgCw

Answer (score 0):

Set the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option of [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to `true` to follow redirection(s):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

For Guzzle, according to [their doc](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3/blob/master/docs/http-client/http-redirects.rst),

> **By default, Guzzle will automatically follow redirects using the
>   non-RFC compliant implementation used by most web browsers**. This means
>   that redirects for POST requests are followed by a GET request. You
>   can force RFC compliance by enabling the strict mode on a request's
>   parameter object:
>
> ```
> // Set per request
> $request = $client->post();
> $request->getParams()->set('redirect.strict', true);
>
> // You can set globally on a client so all requests use strict redirects
> $client->getConfig()->set('request.params', array(
>     'redirect.strict' => true
> ));
> ```
>
> By default, Guzzle will redirect up to 5 times before throwing a
>   `Guzzle\Http\Exception\TooManyRedirectsException`. You can raise or
>   lower this value using the redirect.max parameter of a request object:
>
> ```
> $request->getParams()->set('redirect.max', 2);
> ```

Comment: This is what I've already did. But it doesn't work (the curl approach)

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_real_url($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    $url = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL );
    curl_close($ch);

    return $url;
}
```